# How to convert logic rules to Prolog notation?

Tags: prolog

This is my assignment:
[image]

My attempt was:
a) If Fred is a father of Mike, then Fred is an ancestor of Mike.

```
father( X, Y ). /* X is father of Y */
ancestor( fred, mike ) :- father( fred, mike ).
```

b)  An animal is a mammal if it is a human or its parents were mammals.

```
parent( X, Y ). /* X is parent of Y */
human( X ).     /* X is human */
mammal( X ) :- human( X ).
mammal( X ) :- parent( P, X ), mammal( P ).
```

c)  You have attained the ultimate state if you are happy, healthy, and wise.

```
happy( X ).   /* X is happy */
healthy( X ). /* X is healthy */
wise( X ).    /* X is wise */
attain_ultimate_state( X ) :- happy( X ), healthy( X ), wise( X ).
```

d) Every dog likes all people.

```
dog( X ).    /* X is a dog */
people( Y ). /* Y is human */
like( X, Y ) :- dog( X ), people( Y ).
```

e) The Lakers will win games 2, 3, 5, and 7, but lose the other 3 games in the series with New Orleans.

```
game( one ).
game( two ). 
game( three ).
game( four ).
game( five ).
game( six ).
game( seven ).

win( laker, new_orleans, game( two ) ).
win( laker, new_orleans, game( three ) ).
win( laker, new_orleans, game( five ) ).
win( laker, new_orleans, game( seven ) ).
lose( laker, new_orleans, game( one ) ).
lose( laker, new_orleans, game( four ) ).
lose( laker, new_orleans, game( six ) ).
```

f) If P and Q, then R or S

```
and( X, Y ).     /* X and Y */
or( X, Y ).      /* X or Y */
imply( X, Y ).   /* X imply Y */
or( r, s ) :- and( p, q ).
```

g) P implies Q is equivalent to the disjunction of not P with Q.

```
and( X, Y ).     /* X and Y */
or( X, Y ).      /* X or Y */
imply( X, Y ).   /* X imply Y */
imply( p, q ) == or( not( p ), q ).
```

h) P exclusive_or Q is when P inclusive_or Q, but not (P and Q).

```
and( X, Y ).         /* X and Y */
or( X, Y ).          /* X or Y */
imply( X, Y ).       /* X imply Y */
imply( p, q ) == or( not( p ), q ).
exclusive_or( X, Y ). /* X exclusive or Y */
inclusive_or( X, Y ). /* X inclusive or Y */
exclusive_or( p, q ) :- inclusive_or( p, q ), not( and( p, q ) ).
```

i) Jack is disappointed when it rains and any student misses class.

```
disappointed( X ). /* X is disappointed */
missed_class( X ). /* X missed class */   
rain. /* it rains */
disappointed( jack ) :- rain, missed_class( _ ).
```

j) To be or not to be, that is the question.

```
to_be( X ).
question( X ) :- to_be( X ).
question( X ) :- not( to_be( X ) ).
```

We're using `Concepts of Programming Languages by Robert W. Sebesta` as our textbook for this course. Unfortunately, there are very few examples about how to convert from logic rules to Prolog notation in the book. Although I finished them all, most of my answer was guessing. So I wonder if someone could give me a hint, or suggestion on my work above. Any idea or feedback are welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: OMG, long post. Aren't you worried about the rest of your class seing your assignment verbatim online?

Comment: @mssingno: It's fine, I don't mind. I paid for my class, so whatever I learned is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only imagine i am in your class as we have the same questions and book ;) Only posted 1 hour ago and already it shows up on google, lol

a) Same.

b) Currently this would be true as long as there is one parent that is a mammal, but because the problem says 'parents' and i 2nd guess everything the professor asks us, i specifically checked that there is a mother(M,X), and a father(F,X) and that M and F are mammals.

c) Same

d) more or less same: likes(dog,X):-person(X).

e) *sighs*  This is what i showed to the professor and he didn't seem happy. He said i made it more complicated then it needed to be... but he unhelpful on what that meant.

```
game(1,newOrleans).
game(2,city1).
game(3,city2).
game(4,newOrleans).
game(5,cit2).
game(6,newOrleans).
game(7,city1).
win(X):-game(X,Y), not(city(Y)).
city(newOrleans).
```

f) You don't need imply there as :- stands for imply. I'm still working on f-h. I asked the professor help on this one and all i could get out of him is i didn't need p(x) and can just use p and q.

j) Same, but i have them on one line with ';' to do an or

question( X ) :- to_be(X);not(to_be(X)).

Which i'm not 100% is right. He might be the question needs to be 'to be' or 'not to be' 
question(tobe);question(nottobe).

```
quote(tobe).
quote(nottobe).
question(X):-quote(X).
```

---

**UPDATE**

Forgot 5i),this is what i have.

```
rain(tue). 
skipped_class(tue,frank).
disappointed(jack,Day):-rain(Day), skipped_class(Day,Student).
```

jack will be disappointed on tue as it rain and frank skipped. Not sure if i've done this right but i'm going to stick with this.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Uh i just realized i can use true,false as values and not p. and q.

```
and(P,Q):-P,Q.
inclusive_or(P,Q):-P;Q.
exclusive_or(P,Q):-inclusive_or(P,Q),not(and(P,Q)).
```

Exclusive_or of P and Q will be true if its inclusive or (either P or Q must be true), and not both p and Q are true.

?-exclusive_or(true,true).
false.

Comment: @TheDPQ: Thanks mate! I guess I will have to redo f-h, and we might have to add rules for exlusive_or and inclusive_or by converting them to equivalent logic `and` and `or`.

Comment: 5e) win(X):-member(X,[2,3,5,7]).

Comment: 5f) p.
q.
or(X,Y):-p,q.   still feels weird but i don't think we need an AND function as subgoal since ',' does it for us.

Comment: `and`, `or` and `:-` are what we had. I think we have to come up with something that wrap around these operations.

Comment: Why did you have an extra property for 5i)? I don't get it. Are you sure about 5e). I don't see how we can interpret it this way. I guess it have to have at least two parameters, one for laker, and one for new orleans. Otherwise, they're irrelevant to each others.

Comment: He said i could use list and implied i could forget about tracking new New Orleans. He however wouldn't confirm it. I find if i ask him very direct questions like 'is this right' he won't answer them. He feels like it would be cheating or something ... yup teaching at its best. 

As for 5e, i explicitly instantiate jack as the one who (could be) disappointed. Then it finds a Day and a student in which the subgoal is true (raining AND student skipped on the same day it was raining)

Comment: Teacher on 5j: "No, you are looking to write in Prolog the essence of the quote. Why not use a predicate: The_question_is"

Comment: Teacher's response to 5e: "
This is fine (but it could be even simpler, without lists)"